# Troubleshooting Issues with Application Insights in Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)

Tags: java, azure, kubernetes, azure-application-insights, azure-aks

In my local computer, I run the docker image and see that the Application Insight Azure working fine, but when I use this image and export it as the service on AKS I don't see the Application Insight working or tracking anything when I operate on the web.

Here is my **pom.xml**:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>applicationinsights-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.19</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>applicationinsights-runtime-attach</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.19</version>
    </dependency>
```

My **applicationinsights.json**:

```
  "connectionString": "InstrumentationKey=SECRET",

  "instrumentation": {

    "logging": {

      "level": "DEBUG"

    }

  }
```

My main application:

```
package com.example.springsocial;

import com.example.springsocial.config.AppProperties;
import com.microsoft.applicationinsights.attach.ApplicationInsights;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties(AppProperties.class)
public class SpringSocialApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationInsights.attach();
        SpringApplication.run(SpringSocialApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

My **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM maven:3.8.5-openjdk-17 AS build
COPY . .
RUN mvn clean package -Pprod -DskipTests

FROM openjdk:17.0.1-jdk-slim
EXPOSE 8080
COPY --from=build /target/spring-social-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar spring-social.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","spring-social.jar"]
```

Export deployment on aks using this command:

**kubectl apply -f docker-k8s.yaml**

**docker-k8s.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: docker-k8s-demo-deployment
  labels:
    app: docker-k8s-demo
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: docker-k8s-demo
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: docker-k8s-demo
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: docker-k8s-demo
        image: image here
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```

And then export the service:

kubectl expose deployment docker-k8s-demo-deployment --port=80 --protocol=TCP --target-port=8080 --type=LoadBalancer

Comment: Were you able to successfully build your docker image and push it to Azure Container registry before using it as a deployment image in your yaml?

Answer (score 0):

Here I have changed my version 3.4.9 for azure application insights.

**Pom.xml:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot with Application Insights</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>applicationinsights-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.9</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Working locally and also able to get the trace the logs in my app insight.

- Here while creating cluster also we can see some monitoring configuration.

[image]

**ACR repositories:**
[image]

- I have configured my AKS with the existing container registry so by that I can access my Image.

Now my application is running on AKS cluster and can still I can able to get the logs traced.

[image]